# How to display and edit data of 2 tables in phpmydatagrid

Tags: php, datagrid

I'm using the phpmydatagrid.class.php. Everything is working fine except I can't edit data when I use data from 2 database tables. I got to know from the doc that if I set the column type to "related" instead of integer or text then I can refer data of other table. But the document did not gave further details. The doc's url is http://www.gurusistemas.com/documentation.php

Answer (score 2):

**phpMyDataGrid** is a PHP class to display and edit records of a MySQL database **table**.(And not tables.) Editing can be done via AJAX. It can display the contents of the records in an HTML table. The class can be configured to determine which fields of the database table are displayed.

**The class is capable to save data from only one table currently.** (In future class may provide functionality for multiple tables.) So it is not possible currently to display and edit data of 2 tables in phpmydatagrid.

See [this discussion](http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/2943/thread/7/).

Comment: Was this answer useful to you? Do you get solution which gives How to display and edit data of 2 tables in phpmydatagrid. Else Accept answer   so that it will help other people who have same problem.

Comment: The answer showed me an official reference of what I was already having doubt. But it did not told me how to edit data of 2 tables in phpMyDatagrid.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit several tables with phpMyDataGrid at once if you create an editable view on a join of those tables.
then you just implement the view as you would a table.